# How to change laravel broker

Tags: laravel, eloquent, forgot-password

Can anyone help me with laravel broker function. I have users and sellers page and each has forgot password. It works with users but not in sellers. I tried using ChatGPT to fix my code and it suggests to add sellers in `return Password::broker('sellers');`.

```
class ForgotSellerController extends Controller
{
    use SendsPasswordResetEmails;

    

    public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|email' // Validates the email input
    ]);

    $response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink(
        $request->only('email')
    );

    if ($response) {
        Log::info('Password reset response for sellers: ' . $response);
        return redirect()->back()->with('status', 'An email has been sent!');
    }

    return $response == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
        ? back()->with('status', trans($response))
        : back()->withErrors(['email' => trans($response)]);
}

public function broker()
{
    return Password::broker('sellers');
}
```

How can I separate the 2 tables to have their own forgot passwords?